# Using BSR Mode of 8255 with 8085

Tags: 8085

When using the 8255 to glow an LED array using BSR mode, is it necessary to first set port c as an output port? Why?

In our lab, when I had not not set port C as output and directly used BSR mode to set and reset individual bits, only the 4 led's connected to the lower four bits of port C were responding. When I set port C as output, the desired output was obtained. But what is the need to set port C as output? When we are setting and resetting certain bits in port C, shouldn't port C automatically be taken as an output port?

Answer (score 2):

It is widely standard practice that the output enable of bi-directional/multifunction I/O ports is affected only by the contents of the output configuration / direction register, and not by any change to the data register.

You may think of the bit set/reset mode as being special, but all it is really doing is modifying the data register.  If unaltered, the output/input configuration remains as default, with port C split.

Comment: If port C is not set in output mode and we write a BSR instruction to the control register, will the write fail?

Comment: Check the data sheet and/or conduct a test.